# creating tests for forms: how to see the form's errors when the test assertions fail

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm currently trying to create test for my form which for sure is valid because i were testing him manually in my app, but in my test show me that my form.is_valid == False. I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my test, is there way to check every field seperately to find what causes invalidation in my tested form?

My code:

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms

from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['nick', 'rate', 'content']
        widgets = {'nick': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

test_forms.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ..forms import CommentForm


class CommentFormTest(TestCase):

    def test_form(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='Testowy')
        form_data = {
            'nick': user,
            'rate': '1',
            'content': 'test content',
        }
        form = CommentForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertEqual(form.is_valid(), True)
```

Comment: Write your test like this: `self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(), f"Form should be valid but has following errors: {form.errors}")` so it shows you the form errors.

Comment: so i have problem with my 'nick' field, here should be nick of 1 of already registered users (it's ForeignKey to User model), so i tried to create new user in my test but its not work i have this error "Choose the correct value. Given is not one of the available choices.", is there possibility to create or import user for test purposes?

Comment: In the data that you post, you should post the id of the user: `'nick': user.id`

Comment: thanks, problem solved :)

Comment: But just as a side note: never rely on posted data to associate a comment to a user. Anyone can submit a form with a different user id, even if it's a hidden field.

Comment: in my view.py i have that this file is automatically filled with already logged user(      form = CommentForm(initial={'nick': request.user})), but if this isnt good method then i will look for better methods to do this, thanks for this advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test assertions always have an optional argument (the last one or `msg`) to let you print a message in case the assertion fails. You should use that as much as possible in your tests (unless the result itself is obvious) to help you identify the cause of an assertion failure:

```
self.assertTrue(
    form.is_valid(),  
    msg=f"form should have been valid, but contains errors: {form.errors}")
```

This way the errors will be printed to your test console output.